# request.post how get the body return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm made a test about a external post request. So I start my app this way:

```
var http = require('http');
var extreq = require('./app/external-request');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

     var aaa = extreq.login();

     response.end(JSON.stringify(aaa));

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

And inside the "external-request.js" I have:

```
function login() {
     request.post(url, { form: {
               userid: 'myuserid',
               password: '*****'
          }
     }, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
               var json = JSON.parse(body);
               console.log(json); // Work
               return json; // Not work
          }
     });
}

module.exports.login = login;
```

My problem is, how can I get the "return json" here "var aaa = extreq.login();"?

Comment: You can't. You'll have to design your API so that you pass *in* a callback function. Your "login" function can then pass the object into that callback.

Comment: I tried something like this:

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
        console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
    }
}

request.post(options, callback);

But I got the same problem. So I tried:

login(res) {
     res.end(JSON.stringify(json));
}

But nothing to.

Comment: You have to change the "login()" function so that you can pass a callback into it. See the question linked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `request.post()`.  It's an asynchronous method, so your login function completes and returns before your `request.post()` call completes.  The following will show what's really going on:

```
function login() {
    // obviously, you'll need to make sure you include whatever resources
    // you need from 'external-request.js' before this
    request.post(url, { form: { userid: 'myuserid', password: '*****' } },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                // this will log *after* the note in your main response body
                console.log('this is the second thing your code will log to the console');
                console.log(json); // Work
                // this return doesn't actually go anywhere, it's just lost
                return json; // Not work
            }
    });
    return { whoops: 'this is what we really return' };
}

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    var aaa = extreq.login();

    console.log('this is the first thing your code will log to the console');

    response.end(JSON.stringify(aaa));

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

... run that, and you'll see that your code isn't executing like you expect it to.

When people mention using a callback, what they're saying is that you need to package up the functionality that you want to occur when `request` has finished posting the external request in a callback function, and then it can do its work when it's actually ready.  Something like the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var extreq = require('./app/external-request.js');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    extreq.login(function(aaa) {
        response.end(JSON.stringify(aaa));
    });
    console.log('this is the first thing your code will log to the console');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

... and then, your login function:

```
function login(callback) {
    request.post(url, { form: { userid: 'myuserid', password: '*****' } },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                // this will log *after* the note in your main response body
                console.log('this is the second thing your code will log to the console');
                console.log(json); // Work
                // bonus points: pass in body directly, and skip stringify
                callback(json);
            }
    });
    return { whoops: 'this is what we really return' };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

And any idea about how to show the: "response.end(JSON.stringify(aaa));" on body "response.end('my json');"?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking for here.